# Distributive Property: How come I get a different answer by distributing than by solving inside the parenthesis first?

Tags: arithmetic

Consider the closed phrase:

$$-(2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2)$$

If I distribute $-1$, I get:

$$-1(2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2)=
   -2\cdot-2\cdot-2\cdot-2=
    16$$

If I solve in the parenthesis first:

$$-(2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2)=-(16)=-16$$

Aren't both of these valid ways to solve this phrase?

Comment: multiplication does not distribute over multiplication

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ah, that *would* make a difference. Thank you!

Comment: The distributive property would tell you that $-1 \times(2 + 2 + 2 + 2) = -1 \times 2 + -1 \times 2 + -1 \times 2 + -1 \times 2 $.

Comment: You would be correct to say that the $-1$ multiplies everything in the bracket ... but you would need to understand that $2 \times 2  \times 2 \times 2$ only counts as one thing.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Right! One term. So the distributive property applies only to terms within a group?

Comment: That's right ... littleO's example illustrates several terms ... yours only has one.

Comment: Thank you all! I would be happy to accept an answer that explains that I was mis-using the distributive property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distributive rule says that if $a,b,$ and $c$ are numbers then
$$
a(b + c) = ab + ac.
$$
However, there is no rule which says that
$$
\underbrace{a(bc) = (ab)(ac)}_{\text{usually false}}.
$$